# Reinitialize variables back to starting status in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to ask the user if they would like to play the game again by way of a procedure. If the user selects `Yes` all variables are then set back to starting status and if they select `No`, they simply return to the form. The problem I am having is that I would prefer not to use the `Application.Restart()`, is there a way to initialize the program to start over without using the `Application.Restart()`?

Code For Procedure:

```
 'This Procedure Disables Play Continuation, Asks User To Play Again, & Initializes Starting Status
Sub DisplayPlayAgain()

    'Disable Button That Allows User To Continue Play
    cmdGuess.Enabled = False

    'Display A Button Asking User To Play Again
    Dim answer As DialogResult
    MessageBox.Show("Would You Like To Play Again?", " Confirmation of Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If answer = vbYes Then

        'Reset Variables back to Starting Status
        lstNumberGuess.Items.Clear()
        lblTotalCount.Text = String.Empty
        lblAnswer.Text = String.Empty
        txtUserGuess.Text = String.Empty
        lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)
        shrtCounterTotal = 0
        shrtSecret = shrtRandom.Next(1, 100)

        'Set Focus Back to textbox
        txtUserGuess.Select()

        'Allow User to Play Again
        Application.Restart()
    Else
        'Or if No is selected, return to the form
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't resetting the variables back to starting status enough? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: There's nothing magic to be done.  If you want your fields set to specific values then set them to specific values.  That's it, that's all.  The only other way would be to put all those fields into a class that you can create a new instance of when you want default values.

Comment: If you are restarting the app, resetting the variables will have no effect because that happens again when you restart. I'm assuming by the need to restart you have you game initialization logic in your application start logic. What I would recommend is getting that out to a method you can call from both your start up logic and your play again logic and then you won't need to call `Application.Restart()`

Comment: Thank for the thoughts guys, the problem is that when the user selects yes to play again, the counter has not reset and the listbox continues listing inputs where the previous game left off, because of this I used the restart to get around it, but I would prefer not to, but still cannot figure out where my mistake is, because I have initialized the variables back to "starting status".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `Application.Restart()`

The problem with your code is this:

```
Dim answer As DialogResult
MessageBox.Show("Would You Like To Play Again?", " Confirmation of Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
If answer = vbYes Then
```

You are never assigning the `MessageBox` result to your`answer` variable. Try this:

```
Dim answer As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Would You Like To Play Again?", " Confirmation of Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
If answer = vbYes Then
```

As far as resetting your variables.

You have two options here. First is you manually reset them as you are trying to do. Simplify things can put everything you use to initialize your game inside of a single method and always call that method the start or restart your game:

```
Sub InitGame()
    lstNumberGuess.Items.Clear()
    lblTotalCount.Text = String.Empty
    lblAnswer.Text = String.Empty
    txtUserGuess.Text = String.Empty
    lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)
    shrtCounterTotal = 0
    shrtSecret = shrtRandom.Next(1, 100)

    'Set Focus Back to textbox
    txtUserGuess.Select()

End Sub
```

So to restart:

```
Sub DisplayPlayAgain()

    'Disable Button That Allows User To Continue Play
    cmdGuess.Enabled = False

    'Display A Button Asking User To Play Again
    Dim answer As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Would You Like To Play Again?", " Confirmation of Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If answer = vbYes Then  
        InitGame()
    Else
        'Or if No is selected, return to the form
    End If
End Sub
```

Your other option is to define your game in it's own class and every time you want to start or restart the game you simply create a new instance of the class.

For example, You can move your game into a its own control and wire up an event for when when the game completes. The parent control can decide to create a new game be creating a new instance of the control and loading it.

Something like this:

```
Public Class GameFinishedArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Public PlayAgain As Boolean

    Public Sub New(PlayAgain As Boolean)
        Me.PlayAgain = PlayAgain
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Game
    Inherits Control
    Public Event GameFinished As EventHandler
    Public Sub New()
        lstNumberGuess.Items.Clear()
        lblTotalCount.Text = String.Empty
        lblAnswer.Text = String.Empty
        txtUserGuess.Text = String.Empty
        lblAnswer.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)
        shrtCounterTotal = 0
        shrtSecret = shrtRandom.Next(1, 100)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Game_Load(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.load
        StartGame()
    End Sub
    Sub DisplayPlayAgain()

        'Disable Button That Allows User To Continue Play
        cmdGuess.Enabled = False

        'Display A Button Asking User To Play Again
        Dim answer As DialogResult
        answer = MessageBox.Show("Would You Like To Play Again?", " Confirmation of Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        RaiseEvent GameFinished(Me, New GameFinishedArgs(answer = vbYes))

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Public Sub Form1_Load(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadGame()
    End Sub
    Public Sub LoadGame()
        Dim GameControl As New Game()
        AddHandler GameControl.GameFinished, New EventHandler(AddressOf OnGameFinished)
        GameControl.Top = 0
        GameControl.Left = 0
        GameControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Bottom
        GameControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Me.Controls.Add(GameControl)
    End Sub
    Public Sub OnGameFinished(Sender As Object, E As GameFinishedArgs)
        Dim GameControl As Game = Sender

        RemoveHandler GameControl.GameFinished, New EventHandler(AddressOf OnGameFinished)

        If (E.PlayAgain) Then
            LoadGame()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander